# How come these symbols: +!!"" = 1? c++

Tags: c++

Recently my friend showed me an article that showed +!!"" is == to 1 in C++...
What subject does this fall under ? Where can I look into it ? Why is this true ? I can't find information about this anywhere

Comment: `!!` is a fairly common idiom to create a boolean value from an integer.

Comment: Here `+` and `!` are used as a regular operators. `""` is an empty string.

Comment: The article pretty much explains how it works. What specifically are you having trouble with.

Comment: I guess your friend has taken it from this blog: https://blog.knatten.org/2018/10/12/1662/. There is pretty good explanation

Answer (score 3):

> What subject does this fall under ?

*Implicit conversions*. And *operators*. And *string literals*. All of which are subtopics of *expressions*.

> Where can I look into it ?

The c++ standard is the authoritative specification. There are also unofficial websites that describe the rules.

> Why is this true ?

`""` is a(n empty) string literal. String literals are arrays (of characters). Arrays decay to pointer to first element. The logical NOT operator (`!`) evaluates to false when the operand is a non null pointer. The NOT operator evaluates to true when the operand is false. The unary plus arithmetic operator implicitly converts the operand to integer. True is converted to 1.

Answer (score 1):

`””` is an array of `const char`. In most contexts, an array decays into a pointer to its first element. That’s what happens here. When you apply `!` to a pointer, the result is `true` if the pointer is a null pointer, otherwise it’s `false`. The pointer is not a null pointer, so `!””` has the value `false`. `!false` is `true`, so `!!””` is `true`. Unary `+` promotes smaller types to `int`; in this case, it promotes the value `true` from `bool` to `int`. When `true` is promoted to `int` it becomes 1.